# Sylius eCommerce installation in existing project

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have successfully installed SyliusCartBundle and "add-to-cart" functionality is working fine on product page. So for next process checkout page I need  SyliusWebBundle as mentioned in https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/Cart/summary.html.twig

So I installed SyliusWebBundle through composer  and  When I configured SyliusWebBundle in Appkernel.php then I got this error -

```
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "sylius.menu_builder.frontend" has a dependency on a non-existent service      "sylius.authorization_checker".
```

I am installing this bundles in my existing project for online Buy Option.

Or

Is it not possible to install SyliusWebBundle and other's SyliusBundle in Symfony 2+ Existing project ?

And Please also help me which sylius bundles required for creating a eCommerce system in existing project.

And I am also using Symfony2.6 + SonataAdminBundles

Any Help Will be highly Appreciated !

Thanks  !

Answer (score 0):

`sylius.authorization_checker` is defined in `SyliusRbacBundle`. Since it is required by `SyliusCoreBundle` and `SyliusCoreBundle` is required by `SyliusWebBundle` all you need to do is enable it in kernel:

```
new \Sylius\Bundle\RbacBundle\SyliusRbacBundle()
```

Then [configure](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Docs/blob/master/bundles/SyliusRbacBundle/configuration.rst) it.

Check [docs](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Docs/tree/master/bundles/SyliusRbacBundle) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for help. As you suggested in answer I update my composer and update my appkernel.php file and I got new error :- "The service "sylius.listener.order_promotion" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "sylius.promotion.item_based".

Comment: @sid Just add `sylius.promotion.item_based: false` to your `parameters.yml` ;)